# DocuSign for Dynamics CRM 2015 On Premise

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

Our organization wants to use DocuSign for their Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise application. How can this be done?

Comment: contact docusign support, this question doesn't belong to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XperiDo](http://www.xperido.com/e-sign-your-generated-documents) which offers DocuSign services.

Comment: Have I been downvoted for answering a rubbish question? :/